# What is the best method for taking a string url and encoding it

Tags: java, string, url, encoding

I feel like I must have missed the right thread, because this seems like it would have been clearly answered before, so sorry if it's a repeat.  I read a lot of the threads here and elsewhere and I didn't see a clear "This is how you do it" kind of answer to this question...

The program will be receiving full urls as strings.  For example:
"http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/somepage?somequery#somefragment"

I want to take this string and ensure it is properly encoded for use in a connection like with HttpClient.

From what I read, it seems like the way to do this is to use a URI() constructor with the various parts as parameters.  So that then begs the question, what is the most reliable way to take a string url, that we know nothing about, other than it is a url, and break it up into the various pieces needed for the URI() constructor.

Here is what I pieced together.  Are there any flaws in this method?

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);
```

Then, the uri variable contains a encoded ready to use URI.  This code works so far, but I want to make sure there aren't any pitfalls that might occur.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in certain circumstances. **The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use URI, and to convert between these two classes using toURI() and URI.toURL().** 
Ref: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Note, any **URL instance that complies with RFC 2396 can be converted to a URI**. However, some URLs that are not strictly in compliance can not be converted to a URI.

**URI.toURL** is a convenience method works as if invoking it were equivalent to evaluating the expression `new URL(this.toString())` **after first checking that this URI is absolut**e.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any need to construct a URI. The url constructed using "URL url = new URL(urlString);" is perfectly valid to be used by HttpClient unless the URL construction throws a MalformedURLException.

If you are going to have a query string (for GET), then you have to [URLEncode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) it

Comment: the URL class should be avoided for string manipulation as calling certain methods on it cause network I/O.

Comment: thank you. i was aware of this situation but I have read some where that this has been been fixed in recent versions...can't recollect where though